# Haskell Text.Regex.Posix and Text.Regex.TDFA not working in ghci

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I'm using Windows 10, GHC 8.6.5.

I have used `cabal new-install` on both `Text.Regex.Posix` and `Text.Regex.TDFA` and cabal outputs that it has built them and installed them.

But neither of those modules could not be loaded in ghci.

Now when I run install commands I get  this, first time I did there were messages about building and installing packages.

**Command:**
`cabal new-install regex-posix --lib`

**Output:**

```
Resolving dependencies...
Up to date
```

**Command:**
`cabal new-install regex-tdfa --lib`

**Output:**

```
Resolving dependencies...
Up to date
```

**Command:**
`cabal info regex-posix`

**Output:**

```
* regex-posix      (library)
Synopsis:      POSIX Backend for "Text.Regex" (regex-base)
Versions available: 0.93.1, 0.93.2, 0.94.1, 0.94.2, 0.94.4, 0.95.0, 0.95.1,
                    0.95.2, 0.96.0.0 (and 9 others)
Versions installed: [ Not installed ]
Homepage:      [ Not specified ]
Bug reports:   https://github.com/hvr/regex-posix
Description:   The POSIX regex backend for
               <//hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-base regex-base>.

               The main appeal of this backend is that it's very lightweight
               due to its reliance on the ubiquitous
               <https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/regex.h.html
               POSIX.2 regex> facility that is provided by the standard C
               library on most POSIX platforms.

               See also <https://wiki.haskell.org/Regular_expressions> for
               more information.
Category:      Text
License:       BSD3
Author:        Christopher Kuklewicz
Maintainer:    hvr@gnu.org
Source repo:   https://github.com/hvr/regex-posix.git
Flags:         _regex-posix-clib
Dependencies:  regex-base ==0.94.*, base >=4.3 && <4.14,
               containers >=0.4 && <0.7, bytestring >=0.9 && <0.11,
               array >=0.3 && <0.6, regex-posix-clib ==2.7.*, base <0,
               fail ==4.9.*
Cached:        Yes
Modules:
    Text.Regex.Posix
    Text.Regex.Posix.ByteString
    Text.Regex.Posix.ByteString.Lazy
    Text.Regex.Posix.Sequence
    Text.Regex.Posix.String
    Text.Regex.Posix.Wrap
```

**Command:**
 `cabal info regex-tdfa`

**Output:**

```
* regex-tdfa       (library)
Synopsis:      Pure Haskell Tagged DFA Backend for "Text.Regex" (regex-base)
Versions available: 0.95.2, 0.97.3, 0.97.4, 1.1.8, 1.2.2, 1.2.3.1, 1.2.3.2,
                    1.3.0, 1.3.1.0 (and 16 others)
Versions installed: [ Not installed ]
Homepage:      [ Not specified ]
Bug reports:   https://github.com/hvr/regex-tdfa/issues
Description:   This package provides a pure Haskell \"Tagged\" DFA regex
               engine for <//hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-base
               regex-base>. This implementation was inspired by the
               algorithm (and Master's thesis) behind the regular expression
               library known as <https://github.com/laurikari/tre/ TRE or
               libtre>.

               Please consult the "Text.Regex.TDFA" module for API
               documentation including a tutorial with usage examples; see
               also <https://wiki.haskell.org/Regular_expressions> for
               general information about regular expression support in
               Haskell.
Category:      Text
License:       BSD3
Author:        Christopher Kuklewicz
Maintainer:    hvr@gnu.org
Source repo:   https://github.com/hvr/regex-tdfa.git
Flags:         force-o2
Dependencies:  array >=0.4 && <0.6, base >=4.5 && <4.14,
               bytestring >=0.9.2 && <0.11, containers >=0.4.2 && <0.7,
               mtl >=2.1.3 && <2.3, parsec ==3.1.*, regex-base ==0.94.*,
               text >=1.2.3 && <1.3, fail ==4.9.*,
               semigroups >=0.18 && <0.20, regex-tdfa -any, array -any,
               base -any, bytestring -any, containers -any, filepath -any,
               mtl -any, regex-base -any, text -any,
               directory >=1.1.0 && <1.4, filepath >=1.3.0 && <1.5,
               utf8-string >=1.0.1 && <1.1, fail -any, semigroups -any
Cached:        Yes
Modules:
    Data.IntMap.CharMap2
    Data.IntMap.EnumMap2
    Data.IntSet.EnumSet2
    Text.Regex.TDFA
    Text.Regex.TDFA.ByteString
    Text.Regex.TDFA.ByteString.Lazy
    Text.Regex.TDFA.Common
    Text.Regex.TDFA.CorePattern
    Text.Regex.TDFA.IntArrTrieSet
    Text.Regex.TDFA.NewDFA.Engine
    Text.Regex.TDFA.NewDFA.Engine_FA
    Text.Regex.TDFA.NewDFA.Engine_NC
    Text.Regex.TDFA.NewDFA.Engine_NC_FA
    Text.Regex.TDFA.NewDFA.MakeTest
    Text.Regex.TDFA.NewDFA.Tester
    Text.Regex.TDFA.NewDFA.Uncons
    Text.Regex.TDFA.Pattern
    Text.Regex.TDFA.ReadRegex
    Text.Regex.TDFA.Sequence
    Text.Regex.TDFA.String
    Text.Regex.TDFA.TDFA
    Text.Regex.TDFA.TNFA
    Text.Regex.TDFA.Text
    Text.Regex.TDFA.Text.Lazy
```

Info commands show that neither package has been installed.

I also tried cabal `v1-install` and cabal `v2-install`as well as outdated `cabal install`, same thing.

However when I use cabal to setup and configure package and list those packages in `.cabal` file under `build-depends:` section and use cabal to build an executable, it works.

Why doesn't cabal actually installs those packages with install commands so they work in ghci?

Comment: Please show your *exact* commands and output

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m I posted it bellow.

Comment: Please [edit] your question rather than posting updates as answers

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m You are right, sorry about that, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is essentially as intended. The v2 workflow does not install packages into the global package directory, just the cabal store. The bug is that the `info` command does not show what's in the cabal store, just in global package directory, which leads to this confusion.

You've already arrived at the recommended workflow, which is to explicitly specify dependencies in each project you're working on.